# Non-numbered pages in ReportLab

Tags: python, pdf, reportlab, page-numbering

Is it possible to generate a PDF file using ReportLab in such a way that the front page (and possibly table of contents) are excluded from the page numbering done by Platypus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The first example on chapter 5 of [the user guide](http://www.reportlab.com/docs/reportlab-userguide.pdf), SimpleDocTemplate has two hooks:

```
doc.build(Story, onFirstPage=myFirstPage, onLaterPages=myLaterPages)
```

Just change myLaterPages definition to conditionally print the page number.